# How to change the padding for semantic segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe, caffe2

I am trying to run UNet on my data, which is grayscale images with 256x256 resolution. UNet is downsampling the image to 1-by-5-by-84-by-84 (5 is number of classes). and I am getting the following error:

```
0501 02:16:17.345309  2433 net.cpp:400] loss -> loss
I0501 02:16:17.345317  2433 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
F0501 02:16:17.345377  2433 softmax_loss_layer.cpp:47] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (7056 vs. 65536) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f7d2c9575cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f7d2c959433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f7d2c95715b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f7d2c959e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f7d2d02d4be  caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7f7d2d0c61df  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7f7d2d0c7a91  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7f7d2d0e1a4a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f7d2d0e2db7  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f7d2d0e315a  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7f7d2cf7b9f3  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @           0x40a6d8  train()
    @           0x4075a8  main
    @     0x7f7d2b40b830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x407d19  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

Could someone please let me know how should I set the padding values to get the exactly the input size in the output prediction? I do not know how and which layers should I change.

Comment: Google for "receptive field arithmetics"

Comment: @Shai Thank you very much